# What Happened To The Hips On My Rigged Model?

Tags: armature

I recently converted an Animal Crossing model from an SFM model to a Blender model and just imported it on Blender. But it looks like this.
[image: WHY, GOD?! WHY?!]

The hip looks deformed and it seems to go the opposite direction of where I want it to go when I move the mesh. At the moment, there is LITERALLY nothing I can do about this. Please, help me.

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, 
is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) 
and is [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing).

Comment: Have you checked the weight paint?

Comment: I've found a similar rigged low-poly model. It has only a waist bone but no hip bone. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbOr2.jpg

Comment: @Blunder Both the "bip_hip" groups are nothing but blue.

Comment: Oh wait, I fixed it! I just selected all the bones and cleared the transforms. My character looks back to normal now!